# How can I center a div

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I can center this http://prntscr.com/hv2q7 It is hanging off and I want it to be centered like this http://prntscr.com/hv2ue so that the gray part is coming into the border. Here is the css code and html for it :
The css:

```
#banner{
 height:       279px;
 width:        998px;
 margin-right:   0px;
 margin-left:    0px;
 background-image:
   url(/template/default/images/layout/background/newlayout/test.png);
}
```

The html :

```
<div id="banner" ></div>
```

Comment: CSS protip: Put your properties on different lines. It's a lot easier to manage and a lot more readable that way.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Edited for user1592665

Comment: If `margin: 0 auto` is not working, post the computed style of `#banner`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set your left and right margins to `auto`, not `0px`.

Try this, it's the shorthand for setting your top/bottom margin to `0` and your left/right to `auto`:

```
#banner {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Centering with css normally revolves around the use of `margin:auto;`
In this case you're looking at left and right margins being auto, so something like `margin:0 auto;` As you try it out for your full page specifically you may find you have to set the elements' display to block or the float or even a position, depending on the browser. Though those are usually not necessary.

Also, if the div really only contains the background image, you might set the `background-repeat` to `none` and the `background-position` to `center`. That would only center in the div, so if the div is actually showing as the width and height of the image, it wouldn't change anything, but if the div is filling the width of it's containing block, then you'd get left and right centering.

Comment: @user1592665 I don't recall the exact precedent, but I think for example a `div` won't accept a width making the auto margins less meaningful unless that `div` is floating... or perhaps positioned, I forget which.

Comment: @user1592665 perhaps the width isn't big enough for the image, or the width of the containing div. In these situations it's very useful to inspect the element in a modern browser (like Chrome) and to live-edit the css until you get it displaying the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

put this arround your banner code:

```
<div align="center"> "your banner code" </div>
```

Comment: Use of inline `align` attributes is incredibly dated and completely discouraged.

Comment: Discouraged but generally supported.

Comment: @meagar your answer is unnecessary because it actually works - and he just asked for a working method, so please be kind to others wo use these methods, thank you

Comment: @MauriceA. Voting is how this site works. It's not personal, and it's certainly not "unkind".

Comment: its simply unnecessary, your comment, i mean

Comment: But this does not deserve to be below the `0` vote level so. +1

Comment: This should *absolutely* be below the `0` threshold. It is so dated as to be objectively *incorrect*. By giving this incorrect answer sympathetic up-votes, you're actively harming the quality of content on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @meagar that's clearly an opinion, which you can vote with. It might not be as objective as you think.

Comment: @dlamblin No, the `align` attribute is deprecated. This means, in no uncertain terms, we are to *stop using it*. Introducing it into new code instead of the equivalent CSS is *objectively* wrong. Further, this question is specifically about CSS. This answer is off-topic *and* incorrect.